# Java: Searching for a Regex that splits a text into separate words, including letters, numbers and ' between letters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

At the moment I have: `text.split("[^\\w+]"`
But I also need to include words like: `Can't` but not something like: `'HEART'`

I can't find a solution, that splits a text into words, including the letters, numbers and the aposthroph, if it's between other letters. Thx

Comment: Have you tried splitting on whitespace? Probably something like `text.split("\s+")`.

The only caveat is the possible empty elements at the beginning or end which you can fix by calling `trim()` first.

Comment: Try `(\b[^\s]+\b)`: [split sentences into words with punctuation](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/is-there-a-regex-pattern-that-splits-sentences-into-words.15600/%3famp=1)- adMac231

Comment: `\w+('\w+)?` will match the words you want to include, but it ain't so straightforward to use it with `split` method

Comment: Split on whitespace and aposthrophs with `'?\s'?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be simpler to get rid of the single quotes/apostrophes when they occur before/after the word, and then split using the initial delimiter pattern with excluded apostrophe:

```java
String text = "Modern Talking's Hit:  'You're my heart, you're my soul', 1985";
String[] words = text.replaceAll("(?:^|\\W)'|'(?:\\W|$)", "").split("[^\\w^']+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
```

Output:

```
[Modern, Talking's, Hit, You're, my, heart, you're, my, soul, 1985]
```

Comment: For now I did it similar, but with a simpler regex, as I don't understand to much yet:
`text.replaceAll("\\s'|'\\s", "").split("[^\\w'’]+")`
I see, the `?` should make the following Optional and the `^` seems to reverse things and the `|` is an or Operator? `\W` is not word/number?! Hm, so the first to groups to not make sense to me yet, maybe because of the `:` and/or `$` sign.

Comment: PS: Yes, the results are much better now, with your replace-pattern! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match words using `\w`, instead of using split you can use word boundaries and assert not `'` at the left and at the right.

```
\b(?<!')\w+(?:'\w+)*\b(?!')
```

In Java

```
String regex = "\\b(?<!')\\w+(?:'\\w+)*\\b(?!')";
String string = "Can't but not something like: 'HEART'";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
Can't
but
not
something
like
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, you could use `Pattern` and `MatchResult` libraries to list the words you want with `\w+('\w+)?` regex

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;

String regex = "\\w+('\\w+)?";
String text = "sampl'e 'text'";

String[] words = Pattern.compile(regex)
                          .matcher(text)
                          .results()
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .toArray(String[]::new);
```

You could also split for a whitespace surrounded (or not) by apostrophes

```java
text.split("'?\s'?");
```

Comment: Thx, so I came up with the idea to combine this with my split (that needs to split everywhere between words, and it is quite good, without the need of .replaceAll before, like this: `.split("'?\\s'?|[^\\p{L}']+")`
But still better results with: `.replaceAll("(?:^|\\W)'|'(?:\\W|$)", "").split("[^\\p{L}']+")` - as sometimes there are doublequotes like ''OK''

Comment: cannot edit anymore, split regex would need to be more like: `"['?\\s'?]|[^\\p{L}']+"` and I meant double single quotes (so text that is in many places not well formatted). :-p

Comment: hm, no does not really seem to work, not sure how to use the `|` operator in that case correctly …